# Coldfusion: how get value of the radio button to do the loop?

Tags: coldfusion

For example:

How many item you want to select?   1  2  3 4

If 3 is selected then

loop from 1 to 3

do something

end loop

I want everything process in the same page.  Can someone let me know what I need to do?  I tried cfselect and radio buttons but no luck.  Thank you.

Comment: try posting some of the things you've tried, you will get a better response

Answer (score 1):

I think you're over thinking the problem. The form will return the value of the selected radio button.

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <p>HOW MANY YOU WANT?!? YOU CHOOSE NOW!</p>
    <input type="radio" name="varname" value="1" onclick="this.form.submit();">1
    <input type="radio" name="varname" value="2" onclick="this.form.submit();">2
    <input type="radio" name="varname" value="3" onclick="this.form.submit();">3
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**ColdFusion:**

```
<cfif isDefined("form.varname") AND form.varname GT 0>
    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#form.varname#" step="1">
      <!--- Do Stuff --->
    </cfloop>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Is there any way I can do this without clicking the submit button?

Comment: Add an `onclick="this.form.submit();"` to the radio buttons.